# Is it possible to install program on one PC and use it over lan?

Tags: networking, installation, lan, adobe-photoshop

I want to install Photoshop on one of my LAN PC's, and I wonder if I can do something, so that after the installation I'll be able to use it in the other PC's in the the LAN NETWORK without purchase another licence.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a home or work network?

Comment: home network. 5 PC's.

Comment: That's a fair few... Do you need local storage on the PCs that you are running it from? or just access to the software?

Comment: Just use the software.

Comment: Yeah, Dylan's answer was the one I was leading up to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a remote desktop connection towards the pointed computer that has photoshop installed.

Or is it that you want multiple users to access the application?

**Edit / Remote desktop**

On the photoshop computer
By default, remote desktop is turned off for security reasons. To enable it, go to Control Panel -> System and Security, under the System heading click on Allow Remote access. In the window now opened, tick the Allow Remote Assistance connections to this computer checkbox and the Allow remote connections to this computer checkbox as well.
[image]

Connecting to the photoshop computer
Click on start and type mstsc click on the program that pops up.

[image]

Here you must fill in the IP from the photoshop computer. You can look up the IP by walking over to the photoshop computer, and tap the windows key and type cmd and in the black window type IPCONFIG Under Ehternet adapter ethernet it will say IPv4 address
[image]

Write the IPv4 address down because this is what you use to connect towards the computer. Type the IPv4 address in the remote desktop field.

Comment: Most of the time only one user will use the Photoshop. But the PC he'll use is different every time..

Comment: Well then I think remote desktop is the way to do it. Can you tell me which windows you use?

Comment: If I'll use remote desktop - where the process will run? The source or destionation? - In other words - with this solution I'll be able to use the Photoshop on a weak PC?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: The process will run on the source computer. The only thing you will see is the screen. and ofcourse control the mouse and keyboard. So yes you will be able to use photoshop on the weak computer.

Comment: Thanks. Does the windows have a built-in  remote desktop? Or can you please recommend me of software for that?

Comment: I will edit the answer in a few minutes on how its done. there are a few things that must be done

Comment: oright edited tell me when it doesnt work or something.

Comment: Is it possible to use the source PC while I use it remotely?

Comment: no I dont think so but it is possible with a program called teamviewer.

Comment: I'll try it out...Thanks! until now work great

Comment: Asking for or recommending software is off-topic on this site.